# Use value found by SELECT for multi-value INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

Noob question, but I cannot find answer anywhere. I want to pre-populate my database with some values, which refer to each other via foreign keys. But I see no way to do that without explicitly using IDs, which are supposed to be auto generated and therefore invisible to me. Approach which I hoped would work:

```sql
create table A
(
    id  INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    str TEXT NOT NULL
);

insert into A(str)
values ('a'),
       ('b'),
       ('c');

create table B
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    a  INT REFERENCES A
);

with found as (select id from A where str = 'b')
insert
into B(a)
values (found),
       (found),
       (found);
```

Comment: "Approach which I hoped would work" NO, because of this error:  "ERROR:  column "found" does not exist" **WHY** did you not mention having this error ?  See this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XpVKRfju) for a solution.

Comment: I want to insert multiple values. In real code there will be more fields and more 'constants' from other tables.

Comment: Please share some input-output data to understand your problem properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that only some expressions are allowed as VALUES. I cannot use the table name nor (contrary to the documentation) column reference `found.id`. But I can use a scalar subquery `(select * from found)` or in simpler form `(table found)`:

```
create table A
(
    id  INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    str TEXT NOT NULL
);

insert into A(str)
values ('a'),
       ('b'),
       ('c');

create table B
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    a  INT REFERENCES A
);

with found as (select id from A where str = 'b')
insert
into B(a)
values ((TABLE found)),
       ((TABLE found)),
       ((TABLE found));
```

which is ugly, but works.

Comment: *"contrary to the documentation"* - where [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) does it say you can use a column reference in a [`values` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) (aka table of constants)? Even if you *really do* want to insert into B three copies of the same specific thing from among rows you just inserted into A (that's what your code does), a single statement with a `returning` clause will be faster&safer: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hU5qTwyL). It re-uses values, whereas you're throwing them in, then looking them up.

Comment: @Zegarek the doc does not explicitly state what it means by 'expression', so common sense is to use the only place where something like that is defined: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html . As to your solution, in the real case there will be more fields, some manualy set to specific values - and therefore using INSERT INTO ... SELECT is impossible.

Comment: There's a chapter on [*value expressions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-COLUMN-REFS) but there it's clearly used as a wider term (expressions-that-bring-values-about) and by no means does it refer to the SQL `VALUES` clause used for "manually" materializing a fixed table of fixed values. It has a separate doc entry a bit later, [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html). Edit (I was posting this before your response popped up): you *can* use more fields and you can use "manually set specific values" in a `select`.

Comment: the chapter you mention defines 'expression' as "A constant or expression", which is not really helpfull, and I see no other option than to assume that it refers to chapter https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html - because there are no others.

Comment: Got it. It does sound like it's confusing if you go to the doc with the aim to clarify the rules governing `values` clause, find it say *constant or expression*, then a chapter on *value expressions*, and *constant*, *literal*, *scalar* and *value* being used interchangeably some of the time. Back to what you're trying to achieve: how's a `with a as(insert...returning) select from a` unsuitable and what does it not offer that a `values` clause does?

Comment: `with a as(insert...returning)` will bind the ids only locally. I'm preparing an sql file creating database schema and inserting some initial data.  There will be multiple tables refering to this one, so I need either some global-binding for the ids, or do the `select`s in every `insert` that needs it. From what I read, there is no standard way to bind the ids for duration of executing single file.

Comment: That's an important piece of context, makes total sense now. To confuse things a bit more, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SzKNLZ03)'s a method that not only combines it all, it also proves that after all, you can use an actual *value expression* (in the wider sense of it), in the `values` list. I added that to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77812100/5298879).

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`returning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.5) clause to your `insert into A`, wrap that in a [`with` common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) or a subquery, then select from that when you `insert into B`. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/6GY3enr6)

```
with inserted_into_a as (
    insert into A(str)
    values ('a'),
           ('b'),
           ('c')
    returning id,str)
insert into B(a) select id from inserted_into_a;
```

If you plan to populate a lot of tables and you really need all that `insert...returning`, a plain `select` and `values` clauses have to offer, here's how to combine them all: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/SzKNLZ03)

```sql
with select1 as (select id from A where str = 'b'),
     select2 as (select id from A where str = 'c'),
     insert0 as (insert into A(str) values ('d') returning id)
insert into B(a)
select idv 
from select1,
     select2,
     insert0,
lateral(values(select1.id),
              (select2.id),
              (select2.id),
              (1/*constant*/),
              (insert0.id) )AS vals(idv)
returning *;
```

In theory it's possible to populate the entire structure with a series of `insert...returning` wrapped in CTE's that grab each other's freshly generated identifiers. But given a big enough structure, that quickly gets hard to track and debug and even though it might be faster and safer in terms of IO and concurrency, neither IO nor concurrency might be of concern if all you do is set up a simple test.

---

In PostgreSQL, unless you [double-quote your identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), they are folded to lowercase, so `A` is just `a`, unless you create it as `"A"`.